# Performing Background Tasks – alternative to AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I want to have various asynchronous threads in app like **around 5-10 threads** for background tasks which can be **long running** (like streaming) and I am also **updating the UI** to post some results if necessary.

From what I have heard that AsyncTask has problems with:

- Long running tasks,
- Having poorly being tied to Activity life cycle,
- Device orientation problems, and
- Memory leaks and so on.

So, I am looking an alternative (possibly without using any third party libraries) which doesn't have these above problems.

Should I be better off with using Simple Java Threads? I don't mind using them given that they won't give any problems that are with AsynTask.

Comment: If you want an AsyncTask that is tied to Activity/Fragment lifecycle then you can sub-class the AsyncTaskLoader. BTW running 10 threads is not possible for so many device specially on older ones, which means you need to have an algorithm that scales base on device capacity.

Comment: Yes, not necessarily 10 at a time for all devices but that can be just a possibility to run some of them in parallel while not consuming heavy resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most scenarios `AsyncTask` should suffice the requirement. However there are scenarios where `AsyncTask` can't be used. ie `AsyncTask` manages a thread pool, from which it pulls the threads to be used by task instances. Now the thread pools assume that they'll get their threads back after a reasonable period of time. So in a scenario where you do not know how long you'll need the thread you can't use an `AsyncTask`. And as of Android 4.4 , the size of thread pool can grow only to : `(no of CPU cores * 2) + 1`. So on a dual core processor, the maximum number of threads you can create is limited to 5.

> So, I am looking an alternative (possibly without using any third party libraries) which doesn't have these above problems.

Coming to the alternatives to `AsyncTask`, these are the available options:

- Handler
- Runnable

Now there are cons to all background threads no matter how beautifully illustrated they are, few include:

- The possibility of user's interaction while the background thread is processing. If the work that the background thread performing is altered, you'd need to communicate it back to the background thread. `java.util.concurrent` has many classes to help in these scenarios
- The possibility of the process itself being killed while the thread is performing tasks. So in these cases instead of using an `AsyncTask` or the simpler `Thread` a `Service` or `IntentService` would be an ideal option.
- The possibility of an error occuring inside the background thread, such as retrieving data from server while connectivity is lost, you'd need to manually shut down the background thread.

> In short: Whichever option you choose, you'd need to manually handle
>   all corner cases for the efficient and splendid working of the app.

**PS:**
[Citation] : [The busy coder's guide to Android development v5.8](https://commonsware.com/Android/Android-5.8-CC.pdf) by @Commonsware which is released under the Creative Commons Attribution Non-Commercial Share Alike 4.0 License

Comment: Depends, for networking there already exists some very powerful libraries, See this : https://github.com/shaheenkdr/awesome-android#networking

Comment: Also for REST apis , Retrofit as well . All of which can be customized to a wide extent. Like timeout customization, bandwidth, connection quality, caching, prefetching also proper cancellation of a request etc.

Answer (score 3):

- Long running tasks,
- Having poorly being tied to Activity life cycle,
- Device orientation problems, and
- Memory leaks and so on.

> Simple java threads are not going to solve any of these problems. Specially, **memory leaks.**

If you just want to load data in background, you can think about [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html). They cache the data application wide and fit nicely with activity/fragment  life cycle.

Alternately, you can go through [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) article to know about services (if you don't know already) and see if they are suitable in your scenario.

Comment: Agreed since memory leak is cause by bad implementations and not the thread itself.

Comment: Note that Services are **not** an alternative to AsyncTask because they do **not** automatically spawn a separate thread.

Comment: Yes. That's true.

Comment: Okay so loaders don't have device orientation problems. But are they good for long running tasks such a downloading large files in background e.g. if screen can turns off and is it possible to publish progress?

Comment: No, they are **not**. Consider using a service in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest to use the above mentioned components,

1. Handlers
2. Runnables

If the operation is long running then you can go for service as it runs continuously. You said

> which can be long running (like streaming)

If you are streaming over some audio or video then it is best to use a service either a normal `Service` or an `Intent Service` depending on your requirements.

You can destroy the service when ever needed or let the Android system do it when required.

Hence I would suggest you to use a Service in such a scenario.